# php fscanf with comma separated file

Tags: php

My file contain line of record like

```
HCV,10002,Mich,2,1,HR Dept.,2015-09-27 10:34:47,Attend
```

I tried,

```
$data = fscanf($handle, "%[^ \t\n\r\v\f,]%*c");
list ($a1,$a2,$a3,$a4,$a5,$a6,$a7,$a8) = $data;
```

but no success, please help !

Comment: You want your query to be an array?

Comment: yes, if possible, I have to put the data into mysql then!

Comment: Wrap your data in while loop. For example: `while($data = fscanf($handle, "%[^ \t\n\r\v\f,]%*c")) { list ($a1,$a2,$a3,$a4,$a5,$a6,$a7,$a8) = $data; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_getcsv` for each line in file. See my code below:

```
$file = 'HCV,10002,Mich,2,1,HR Dept.,2015-09-27 10:34:47,Attend
HCV2,10002,Mich,2,1,HR Dept.,2015-09-27 10:34:47,Attend
HCV5,10002,Mich,2,1,HR Dept.,2015-09-27 10:34:47,Attend';

$result = [];
foreach (explode(PHP_EOL, $file) as $line) {
    $result[] = str_getcsv($line);
}
print_r($result);
```

It will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => HCV
            [1] => 10002
            [2] => Mich
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 1
            [5] => HR Dept.
            [6] => 2015-09-27 10:34:47
            [7] => Attend
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => HCV2
            [1] => 10002
            [2] => Mich
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 1
            [5] => HR Dept.
            [6] => 2015-09-27 10:34:47
            [7] => Attend
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => HCV5
            [1] => 10002
            [2] => Mich
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 1
            [5] => HR Dept.
            [6] => 2015-09-27 10:34:47
            [7] => Attend
        )
```